# How to two SELECT queries as a single table with one table having an aggregate column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different SQL queries and they are generating below results.

```
SELECT dbo.HomeUnit.unit_id
     , dbo.HomeUnit.type_id
     , dbo.UnitType.[type]
     , HomeUnit.unitqty
FROM dbo.HomeUnit
    INNER JOIN dbo.UnitType ON dbo.HomeUnit.type_id = dbo.UnitType.type_id
WHERE home_id='H2L54'
```

This delivers a result like below

```
unit_id | type_id | type         | unitqty
UG4LG   |  UTUEP  | Driver's Bed |    6
UQTK6   |  UTFX5  | Normal Unit  |   14
UQTJ6   |  UTFG5  | Normal Unit  |   12
```

This is the second query:

```
SELECT unit_id
     , home_id
     , SUM(numberofunits) as totalunitsbooked
FROM View_Reservation_With_Unit
WHERE home_id = 'H2L54'
    AND reservation_status='1'
    AND (NOT (fromdate > '2017-09-25' OR todate < '2017-09-26'))
GROUP BY home_id, unit_id
```

Output of above query gets me this

```
unit_id | home_id | totalunitsbooked
U3CFF   |  H2L54  |  5
UFRXJ   |  H2L54  |  1
```

My question is: How can I put the column "totalunitsbooked" in the first result set as an column, and assigning 0 if there's no units are booked.

Comment: `PS: I'm sorry for the bad formatting.` https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156729/how-to-display-data-in-table-structure-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT h.unit_id
     , h.type_id
     , u.[type]
     , h.unitqty
     , SUM(ISNULL(v.reservation_status,0)) as totalunitsbooked
FROM dbo.HomeUnit h
    INNER JOIN dbo.UnitType u ON h.type_id = u.type_id
    LEFT JOIN View_Reservation_With_Unit v ON v.unit_id = h.unit_id
        AND v.reservation_status = '1' AND (NOT (fromdate > '2017-09-25' OR todate < '2017-09-26'))
WHERE home_id='H2L54'
GROUP BY h.unit_id, h.type_id, u.[type], h.unitqty
```

What I did was to include your second query as a `LEFT JOIN` (or else all units not in the view wouldn't get displayed) and then made use of the `ISNULL` function to simply display 0 for all units that are not booked.

The aliases are just for readability.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but the quick and easy way of doing this is a join on the second query:

```
SELECT dbo.HomeUnit.unit_id
     , dbo.HomeUnit.type_id
     , dbo.UnitType.[type]
     , HomeUnit.unitqty
FROM dbo.HomeUnit
    INNER JOIN dbo.UnitType ON dbo.HomeUnit.type_id = dbo.UnitType.type_id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT unit_id
             , home_id
             , SUM(numberofunits) as totalunitsbooked
        FROM View_Reservation_With_Unit
        WHERE home_id = 'H2L54'
            AND reservation_status='1'
            AND (NOT (fromdate > '2017-09-25' OR todate < '2017-09-26')
    )
    ON dbo.HomeUnit.unit_id = unit_id
GROUP BY home_id, unit_id)
WHERE home_id='H2L54'
```

It would probably be more efficient to join them properly and have the group-by outside the "subquery" (like the other answer!)